# How to create custom slot in alexa skill as similar to built in slot and use that slot in another skill

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-smapi

I want to create a custom slot type using smapi in Alexa skill as similar to  built-in slot  and extend the slot in another created skill

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can't mix your custom slots across multiple skills. You can export the JSON in the editor and then import it into your other skill